# Mathematica Beginners Help

Tags: reference-request

I am new to Mathematica syntax and was wondering if anyone has any links to, say, a .pdf with a lot of the basic beginner commands.

I am aware of the help functions in Mathematica, but it would be super handy to have a sheet with these listed!

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/HowToTopics.html